# monaco editor how do I check for model changes?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am looking for an API method that will determine if a save button should be enabled or disabled following the editor's content changing or matching its original state.  I.E. I only want to permit save if there is a change to save.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this would be gratefully received? Thanks in advance.